# Replacing diagonal elements using dplyr pipe

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to replace the diagonal elements of a matrix in the middle of a piping process but can't figure out a way to do this. I know I can replace the diagonal elements this using `diag()` function, but I just don't know how to use `diag()` function inside a piping process. Sample data is given below and I want the following steps put together in a piping process. Thanks in advance.

```
aa <- matrix(1:25, nrow =5) 
diag(aa) <- NA
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use `replace` with a logical condition

```
library(dplyr)
aa %>% 
     replace(., col(.) == row(.), NA)
```

-output

```
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]   NA    6   11   16   21
#[2,]    2   NA   12   17   22
#[3,]    3    8   NA   18   23
#[4,]    4    9   14   NA   24
#[5,]    5   10   15   20   NA
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this is more piping-friendly approach than using an assignment operator.

Answer (score 4):

One option could be:

```
aa %>%
 `diag<-`(., NA)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   NA    6   11   16   21
[2,]    2   NA   12   17   22
[3,]    3    8   NA   18   23
[4,]    4    9   14   NA   24
[5,]    5   10   15   20   NA
```

Comment: I was trying __aa %>%
 `diag<-`NA_ _and didn't work. Thanks for showing me the right way to do this.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is the right way, it's just one way to do it :)

Comment: Can you please explain how the assignment operator work here? I am a little puzzled how the normal brackets `()` can be used here without an associated function. They are not the arguments for the `diag()` function either

Comment: Look at `View(`diag<-`)`. You can see how it's defined.